# Reference for a Cantor set in the plane formed from series of roots of unity

Tags: analysis, reference-request, fractals

This is a long shot, but I'm looking for a particular article that I once read, and I'm trying to find it again. It deals with a certain Cantor set in the plane. The set could be written as something like this:
$$C=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\exp\frac{2\pi i\mathbb Z}{n}.$$
In other words, $C$ contains all sums of series whose $n$th term is an $n$th root of unity multiplied by a quickly decreasing sequence of scales. The scales might not have been $1/n^2$; that's just a guess. The set is composed of two side-by-side blobs, each of which is a triangle of three smaller blobs, each of which is a diamond of four blobs, each of which is a ring of five blobs, each of which is a ring of six blobs, etc. It's sort of a disconnected multi-gasket... fractal thingy.

The article definitely included a computer-generated diagram of $C$, maybe two or three. I want to say that it had a preprint on arXiv, but I'm not sure. I don't think it was particularly focused on $C$, so the definition and the diagram(s) would occur somewhere in the middle of the article, and the abstract probably doesn't mention $C$ at all.

I don't remember anything else about the context, including the article's mathematical content! I know why *I'm* suddenly interested in $C$: it's a seemingly rare example of a Cantor set that doesn't contain any "corner point": a point whose Bouligand tangent cone is contained in an open half-space. But I don't remember why the author(s) introduced the example in the first place. When I saw the article, I was just searching for Cantor sets with interesting geometry, not for any particular result.

Does anyone know the reference I'm looking for? If not, maybe there are suggestions on how one would search for such a thing? Can you divine what the context must have been?

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills Maybe I misunderstand, but the Cantor set $X$ you describe does have corner points, including the four midpoints of the sides of the original square, since $X$ is a subset of the diamond whose vertices are those midpoints.

Comment: Right, that example did not work. How about this one: begin with the square. At step $n$, divide it into $(n+4)\times (n+4)$ smaller squares. Keep $n$ middle squares along each side, discard the rest.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills For that example, here's a corner point: at each stage of the construction, choose the topmost remaining square on the right side. The tangent cone from this point is contained in the angle $[3\pi/4, 3\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Victory!* The winning query was ["cantor" + "regular polygon"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22cantor%22+%22regular+polygon%22).

> Aleš Nekvinda and Ondřej Zindulka (2011), "A Cantor set in the plane that is not $\sigma$-monotone", *Fundamenta Mathematicae* **213** (3), 221–232, doi:[10.4064/fm213-3-3](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm213-3-3). Free preprint: [link1](http://mat.fsv.cvut.cz/nales/publikace/monotone1.pdf), [link2](http://mat.fsv.cvut.cz/zindulka/papers/monotone1.pdf)